# XgBoost error: contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

Tags: r, xgboost, error-handling

```
Error in XGBoost: Error in contrasts<-(tmp, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]): 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

param <- list(  objective           = "binary:logistic", 
                booster             = "gbtree",
                eval_metric         = "auc",
                eta                 = 0.01,
                max_depth           = 5,
                subsample           = 0.6,
                colsample_bytree    = 0.6
)


t1.y <- t1$target   

t1 <- sparse.model.matrix(target ~ ., data = t1)
#Error occurs after the above command. If i change the above statement to (replacing . by -1 to drop collinear columns)
t1 <- sparse.model.matrix(target ~ -1, data = t1)
```

No error occurs after changing to -1 but the dgcMatrix that is generated looks suspicious as it contains just one column and lot of rows. I was expecting the columns of the original matrix to be one-hot encoded rather than getting one columns as an output. If i proceed further ignoring the inspection of generated sparse matrix then I get an error after i run the xgboost below:

```
Error in xgb.iter.update(bst$handle, dtrain, iteration - 1, obj) : 
  [05:14:55] amalgamation/../src/objective/regression_obj.cc:108: label must be in [0,1] for logistic regression


dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(data=t1, label=t1.y)
watchlist <- list(train=dtrain)
bst1 <- xgboost(   params              = param, 
                   data                = dtrain, 
                   nrounds             = 1750,
                   #watchlist           = watchlist,
                   verbose             = 1,
                   maximize            = FALSE
)
```

I tried to convert the target column to both factor and numeric (converted it to 0 & 1, since as.numeric converts it to 1 & 2). But it did not help :'(

When I convert the target to numeric then after running the Xgboost, I get the following error : `Error in xgb.iter.update(bst$handle, dtrain, iteration - 1, obj) : 
  [05:20:12] amalgamation/../src/tree/updater_colmaker.cc:162: Check failed: (n) > (0) colsample_bytree=0.6 is too small that no feature can be included`

*t1 is a data.frame initially containing factor,numeric and integers which i am converting to sparse matrix

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Good answer over here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200195/how-to-debug-contrasts-can-be-applied-only-to-factors-with-2-or-more-levels-er